# Limit of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a real sequence and let $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence in the set of limit points of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $L(a_n)$.

There is also a $b_0\in \mathbb{R}$ with $b_n\rightarrow b_0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I want to show that then $b_0\in L(a_n)$.

We have that $b_n\in H(a_n)$ is a limit point of $(a_n)$ if every neighbourhood of $b_n$ contains at least one point of $(a_n)$ different from $b_n$ itself, right?

Let $y_n$ be that point. 
So we have then that $|y_n-b_n|>0$ ?

If $b_n=b_0$ for some $n$ then we have that $b_0\in L(a_n)$. 
If $b_n\neq b_0, \forall n$ then from  the above defintion $0<|y_n-b_n|<|b_n-b_0|$.

Is this correct? Does this help?

Comment: There are too many $a_n$ s in your question. My feeling is that some of these $a_n$ s are different from the others. Could you either change the names of those that are different, or make your question clearer via words? Because the question is unintelligible at the moment.

Comment: I edited my question... @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: @Mary Star Could you tell us what is the definition of limit point that you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

Let $i_1\geq 1$ such that $a_{i_1}\not=b_0$, and let $k\geq 2$.

i) If $b_n\to b_0$ then there is $N\geq 1$ such that 
$|b_N-b_0|<1/k$.

ii) Since $b_N$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$, there is a $i_k>i_{k-1}$ such that  $|b_N-a_{i_k}|<1/k$. Take $i_k$ large enough such that $a_{i_k}\not=b_0$.

Hence $(a_{i_k})_{k\geq 1}$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $a_{i_k}\to b_0$ because
$$|a_{i_k}-b_0|\leq |b_N-a_{i_k}|+|b_N-b_0|<2/k.$$
Therefore $b_0$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$.

P.S. Here $b$ is an limit point (or accumulation point) of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ if and only if there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ such that $a_{n_k} \rightarrow b$ AND $a_{n_k} \neq b$ for $k=1,2,...$

Comment: I'm not sure about $a_{i_k}\ne b_0$. After all, $0$ is a limit point of a constant sequence. If you don't consider such points, then the theorem about any bounded sequence having a limit point doesn't hold.

Comment: I think that here limit point should be intended as an accumulation point.

Comment: But then a constant sequence has no limit point. In my books, limit points of sequences are where a subsequence converges.

Comment: What is the definition of limit point of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq }$ that we are using here?